# Can't add policy to SOAP API in WSO2 APIM 4.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have create a SOAP API in WSO2 APIM 4.1.0 ,i need to add a policy to this API but i can't find the page policies as i found it in REST API ,even i have followed this documentation.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/design/api-policies/create-policy/#creating-a-common-policy

[image: can't found policy page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API polices for SOAP APIs and SOAP To REST APIs are not found in the GA release of APIM 4.1.0. Latest updated 4.1.0 or 4.2.0 distribution support API policies for these types of APIs.

Comment: How can i update my 4.1.0 version ? is there a link to the updates or any documentation to follow to update WSO2 APIM ?

Comment: If you have WSO2 subscription, you can update the API Manager. https://wso2.com/subscription/.

Comment: For the open source version, you can either port the improvement attached to this git issue. https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/12559